# ReactJS: How to call a parent's setState() from this.props.children?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a parent component that is used by the React Router, with a render function similar to:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Breadcrumb>
                    {this.state.breadcrumbs}
                </Breadcrumb>
                {this.props.children}
            </Grid>
        );
    }
```

And one of the children will attempt to fetch() some JSON. This json will contain some extra information that I want to update the parent's `this.state.breadcrumbs`, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

**Parent component**

```
updateState(newState){
  this.setState({
    breadcrumbs: newState,
  })
}

 render() {
   var childrenwithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child){
     return React.cloneElement(child, {
      updateParentState: this.updateState
     })
   })
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Breadcrumb>
                    {this.state.breadcrumbs}
                </Breadcrumb>
                {childrenwithProps}
            </Grid>
        );
    }
```

**Child Component**

```
fetch()
.then()
.then(function(data){
  this.props.updateParentState(data)
})
```

Pass the function which will change the state of the parent as a prop to the children. From the child, call this function by `this.props.updateState` with the new state as a parameter. This will update the state of the parent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Performance wise... is this slow? Since cloning elements in general seems like it's not good to do...

Comment: @Ben You don't have an option because to send any information to this.props.children you need to clone it with new props. Performance wise I don't think it'll impact a lot. The good thing you can do is, clone only necessary child by checking it in the loop. This will reduce the performance impact.